# Whats a concise formula for converting an N amount of hours into their respective minutes (Excel)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, cell

To explain this better, let's use an example.

| Number cell(AA1) | perHour formula(AA1/12) | perMinute formula(???) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2.5 | ? |
| 45 | 3.75 | ? |

The idea is to have the per minute formula convert whatever number is placed in the perHour formula cells into the minute equivalent. Basically reading it as if the numbers themselves are representative of hours. the 12 listed above is for how long the work shift is.

I feel like it's super simple, and maybe it's just my brain being mush on a hectic Thursday, but I tried all sorts of conversions and the like and it doesn't appear to be working or reading right.

dividing the perhour value by 60 doesn't work, because it doesn't represent the correct minute. and using the functions in excel that convert from hours to minutes don't work either. Is it because I am supposed to do more to the middle column first?

Comment: `=AA1/(12*60)`?

Comment: if you do 2.5 per hour then 2.5 divided by 60 is the number per minute.  I do not understand why you think it wrong.  2.5 per hour means it takes 24 minutes to do one which is 0.04167 per minute.

Comment: It's because in another cell, where it was supposed to read 15, it was coming out with 8 for some reason. I think it might actually have to do with the format of the cells though, I tried to change it to reflect the time format and it seems to be working now.

Comment: The cells should be formatted general as you are not returning a time but a number per.